# parsing JSON in php using angularJS object

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I am trying to pass JSON object from angular to php like this :

```
<?php
    $placeBean = "{{masterCtrl.getLastplace();}}";
    //VAR DUMP IS -> string(30) "{"id":1841,"name":"Milano","areaCode":"MI","latitude":0,"longitude":0}"

    $json = '{"id":1841,"name":"Milano","areaCode":"MI","latitude":0,"longitude":0}';
    //VAR DUMP IS -> string(70) "{"id":1841,"name":"Milano","areaCode":"MI","latitude":0,"longitude":0}"
?>
```

Then I need to parse the json in $placeBean, because it is not yet a json in php, so I use

```
<?php 
   $manage = json_decode($placeBean);  
?>
```

And this is the problem... because it doesn't work, in fact the result is an empty value: instead, if I do the same thing with $json( instead of $placeBean), the code works perfectly.
I Think the issue is some
missing chars, which are placed in$json, and not in $placeBean.

Those are the echo of the variables

ECHO OF JSON ->{"id":1841,"name":"Milano","areaCode":"MI","latitude":0,"longitude":0}

ECHO OF placeBean ->
placeBean{"id":1841,"name":"Milano","areaCode":"MI","latitude":0,"longitude":0}

I Also tried to use json_last_error, which gave me this :  - Syntax error, malformed

Comment: try to use correct string - the string you are trying to parse isn't a valid json

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: The problem is that the string inside $json, is a simple copy/paste of echo($placeBean );

Comment: this is the dump string(32) ""{"id":1841,"name":"Milano","areaCode":"MI","latitude":0,"longitude":0}"" bool(false)

Comment: Somewhere its adding an extra doublequotes on the string value. What is the exact 'raw' output of php in your browser when you do: `echo $placeBean;` and `echo $json;` after those two lines you show at the start of your question?

Comment: added the two echo

Comment: With all the edits (why do you think you should keep them separate?) the question has become even less understandable. How about you provide an MCVE as per site guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first one is not a valid JSON object, for this PHP refuses to parse it.

When you run it though AngularJS it will actually use its own mechanism and replaces the string with the data returned by the `masterCtrl.getLastplace()` call.

Comment: I am still stucked on this... I understand why the var-dump has different lenght... that is why if I use addcslashes  on the two strings, I got for the $json, the correct value, while for the $placeBean  , I got this :   {{\m\a\s\t\e\r\C\t\r\l.\g\e\t\L\a\s\t\p\l\a\c\e();}}

Comment: What I mean is, when you call $json, this function relies on local data and internal logic for transpiling the string with a function call into a valid JavaScript object. The PHP code does not expect this kind of behaviour and does not implement the logic for so. This way, you will not be able to have the PHP code do behave the same as an Angular specific code.